# How to show the intersecting side of 2 shapes in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, intersection, collider

I want to create a game 2d in unity. I have a simple (main) square shape. Then, when I click on the screen, should be added another square. At each addition of a new square, I have to get an intersect, and from this intersect I have to get a new form for main shape. That is, change the shape. How many times I click so many times should appear a new square. How can this be realized?
[image]

Comment: or how to merge two shapes and create one?

Comment: Can you provide any thoughts or code you have so far? This is computational geometry problem, where you are looking at the Union of squares.

Comment: It would help if your image above was squares, not circles. Can you show an image specifying the algorithm you are after.